# Need to figure out how to replace the comma in the array list for a space

Tags: java, arraylist, replaceall, removeall

I have tried to use `replaceAll` and `removeAll` but still can't change the list without commas.
I tried to add after list + ""); but nothing changed. Still get the output with commas.
I need to remove the commas in the output. Need only one white space between numbers. (See at the end the output)

> (Remove duplicates) Write a method that removes the duplicate elements from an array list of integers using the following header:
> `public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list)`
> Write a test program that prompts the user to enter 10 integers to a list and displays the distinct integers separated by exactly one space.

```
package exercise11_13;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise11_13 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create de Scanner object.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Prompt the user to enter ten integer numbers. 
        System.out.print("Please, enter ten (10) integers numbers: ");
        
        // Create the ListArray (List object).
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) list.add(input.nextInt());

        removeDuplicate(list);
        
        System.out.println("Display the distinct integers in their input order "
                + "and seperated by exactly one space: " + "\n" + list );
    }

    public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            if (!temp.contains(list.get(i))) {
                temp.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(temp);
        
    }
}
```

Output: I need to remove the commas in the output. Need only one white space between numbers.
run:

```
Please, enter ten (10) integers numbers: 78
99
54
63
56
78
63
14
67
99
Display the distinct integers in their input order and seperated by exactly one space: 
[78, 99, 54, 63, 56, 14, 67]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 27 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question is tagged with `replaceAll`, it is indeed possible to remove all "redundant" characters supplied by `List::toString` method (brackets and commas) using a regular expression `[,\[\]]` (brackets should be escaped with `\`):

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
System.out.println(list.toString().replaceAll("[,\\[\\]]", "")); // 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or, knowing that the brackets are the first and the last characters, they can be removed with the help of `substring` and then apply `String::replace`:

```java
String str = list.toString();
    
System.out.println(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).replace(",", "")); // 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Alex, Thank you! It is great to have help from you guys. Your solution is shorter and works as well.                                                                                                                
 run:
Please, enter ten (10) integers numbers: 45
67
87
23
56
67
87
95
1
23

Display the distinct integers in their input order and separated by exactly one space: 
45 67 87 23 56 95 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 26 seconds)

Answer (score 2):

When you use an object like that, it's implicitly converted to a string by its `toString` method. You shouldn't rely on the list's implementation of `toString`, but instead convert it to the string you need yourself. Here, you could stream the list and join it with a space:

```java
System.out.println(
   "Display the distinct integers in their input order and separated by exactly one space: \n" + 
   list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
);
```

Comment: Mureinik, it is not working. I got errors: "No suitable method for collect(collector<CharSequence,CAP#1String>)

Comment: @mpena1s forgot to convert the Integers to stings, my bad. See my edited answer.

Comment: Mureinik, Thank you so much! You can not imagine how many articles I have read to try to find a solution. I need to study and practice more. The commas have been removed and a got the onw white space. Thanks again.                                                             
 run:
Please, enter ten (10) integers numbers: 45
54
67
89
93
54
23
67
54
75
Display the distinct integers in their input order and separated by exactly one space: 
45 54 67 89 93 23 75
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 25 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to replace the commas for white space in this program.

The long one:
Need to add:
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

```
System.out.println("Display the distinct integers in their input "
                + "order and separated by exactly one space: "
                + "\n" 
                + 
                list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("")));
```

The short one:

```
System.out.println("\nDisplay the distinct integers in their input "
                + "order and separated by exactly one space: "
                + "\n" + list.toString().replaceAll("[,\\[\\]]", ""));
```

Below the entire program.

```
package exercise11_13;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class Exercise11_13 {
    
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        // Main method
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Create de Scanner object.
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            // Prompt the user to enter ten integer numbers. 
            System.out.print("Please, enter ten (10) integers numbers: ");
            
            // Create the ListArray (List object).
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) list.add(input.nextInt());
    
            removeDuplicate(list);
            /**
            System.out.println("Display the distinct integers in their input "
                    + "order and separated by exactly one space: "
                    + "\n" + 
            list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
            */
            System.out.println("\nDisplay the distinct integers in their input "
                    + "order and separated by exactly one space: "
                    + "\n" + list.toString().replaceAll("[,\\[\\]]", ""));         
        }
    
        public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    
                if (!temp.contains(list.get(i))) {
                    temp.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }
            list.clear();
            list.addAll(temp);
            
        }
    }
```